# NSData dataWithContentsOfURL fail

Tags: ios, nsdata

The method returns nil, and logs:

> MSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9814)

I Googled the specific error and couldn't find anything related; I used the browser (Safari) with the same url and got good results; I tried using `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error` and looked for the returned error: "The operation couldn't be completed (Cocoa error 256)" and checked the error code as well. Didn't help. Any idea where to go on from here?

Comment: Share some code, how did you call it?

Comment: It says SSL - could it be you need to accept a certificate? code would help ...

Comment: @dogsgod i do need a certificate that's supplied with the url.

this is my code:
NSURL *urlForTopPlaces = [FlickrFetcher URLforTopPlaces];
    NSData *dataForTopPlaces = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlForTopPlaces];


urlForTopPlaces == https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.places.getTopPlacesList&place_type_id=7&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_key=22ff1183309ab4679d17b3ac2d5e165a

Comment: is your scheme http or https? As it seems to be flickr I guess the certificate is valid, and you don't need to worry - but in that case you don't have a certificate issue ... try to call the url in safari. if you don't get a warning you have a different issue.

Comment: it's https, and i've tried calling it on safari and got the required JSON in response. that's why i find it so weird

Comment: Problem Solved: apparently the date on my computer is set to 2012 and so the returned TSL certificate from the server was failing because (to my understanding) my computer's date didn't comply with the valid date range in the certificate.

i still wonder why it worked when i used Safari (the computer's date is still erroneous) - any thoughts on that?

and thanks so much for you help!